# Error 400 when writing variant with excel Function to listobject

Tags: vba

I'm getting very cofused.
I'm assigning some data to a variant(vOrderdata) and then printing the variant to a new table row.
Everything works out, but when If I add the formula to vorderdata(7) I get error 400.
The code still works, but it raises an error 400.
Should I just capture the error and ignore it or is there actually something wrong?

```
    Dim vOrderData(1 To 9) As Variant
    Set loorder = Worksheets("Orderhantering").ListObjects("tblOrderdata")
    vOrderData(1) = lOrdernumber
    vOrderData(2) = sSuppliernumber
    vOrderData(3) = sProjectnumber
    vOrderData(4) = Date
    vOrderData(5) = wsS.range("C15").Value
    vOrderData(6) = "Genererad"
    vOrderData(7) = "=SUMIF(Orderhistorik!I:I;[@Ordernr];Orderhistorik!F:F)"
    loorder.ListRows.Add
    lLastRow = loorder.DataBodyRange.rows.Count
    loorder.ListRows(lLastRow).range.Value = vOrderData
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: You are using vorderdata as an array so please show us the declaration of vorderdata

Comment: thanks, Updated it now, its a variant array

Comment: which line gives the error?